# scikit learn: how to check coefficients significance

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, anova, dummy-data

i tried to do a LR with SKLearn for a rather large dataset with ~600 dummy and only few interval variables (and 300 K lines in my dataset) and the resulting confusion matrix looks suspicious. I wanted to check the significance of the returned coefficients and ANOVA but I cannot find how to access it. Is it possible at all? And what is the best strategy for data that contains lots of dummy variables? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your logistic regression object is called `lr`, try looking at `lr.coef_`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no, well, coef_ is the coefficients value, and i want is the significance of this value: z-score and the p-value. its when you assume a test hypothesis that the coefficient is 0 (null hypothesis H_0=0) and an alternative hypothesis H_1!=0, and then p-value tells you basically if you can reject the H_0 (when the H_0 is tiny) or not (when H_0->1)

Comment: With logistic regression I have the feeling that you can only get those using resampling and building empirical distributions on the `coef_` of each sample.

Comment: well, yes, but i was wondering if there is a built-in method with sklearn, like the summary for a "glm class" object in R...

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't one. If this feature exists in R, why don't you use R? In any case, this type of classic statistic for e.g. linear regression only works in the `n_samples <= n_features` setting.

Comment: i actually did what you suggested with building empirical distributions for sub-samples - worked nicely! Thank you!

Comment: If that was helpful you may also check stability selection and the sklearn implementations of randomized logistic regression. These can provide you with a stable selection of features.

Answer (score 28):

Scikit-learn deliberately does not support statistical inference. If you want out-of-the-box coefficients significance tests (and much more), you can use [Logit](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html) estimator from **Statsmodels**. This package mimics interface `glm` models in R, so you could find it familiar.

If you still want to stick to scikit-learn LogisticRegression, you can use asymtotic approximation to distribution of maximum likelihiood estimates. Precisely, for a vector of maximum likelihood estimates `theta`, its variance-covariance matrix can be estimated as `inverse(H)`, where `H` is the Hessian matrix of log-likelihood at `theta`. This is exactly what the function below does:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def logit_pvalue(model, x):
    """ Calculate z-scores for scikit-learn LogisticRegression.
    parameters:
        model: fitted sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression with intercept and large C
        x:     matrix on which the model was fit
    This function uses asymtptics for maximum likelihood estimates.
    """
    p = model.predict_proba(x)
    n = len(p)
    m = len(model.coef_[0]) + 1
    coefs = np.concatenate([model.intercept_, model.coef_[0]])
    x_full = np.matrix(np.insert(np.array(x), 0, 1, axis = 1))
    ans = np.zeros((m, m))
    for i in range(n):
        ans = ans + np.dot(np.transpose(x_full[i, :]), x_full[i, :]) * p[i,1] * p[i, 0]
    vcov = np.linalg.inv(np.matrix(ans))
    se = np.sqrt(np.diag(vcov))
    t =  coefs/se  
    p = (1 - norm.cdf(abs(t))) * 2
    return p

# test p-values
x = np.arange(10)[:, np.newaxis]
y = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1])
model = LogisticRegression(C=1e30).fit(x, y)
print(logit_pvalue(model, x))

# compare with statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm_model = sm.Logit(y, sm.add_constant(x)).fit(disp=0)
print(sm_model.pvalues)
sm_model.summary()
```

The outputs of `print()` are identical, and they happen to be coefficient p-values.

```
[ 0.11413093  0.08779978]
[ 0.11413093  0.08779979]
```

`sm_model.summary()` also prints a nicely formatted HTML summary.

Comment: Thank you a lot  for your answer, how is p_value  reliable and do statsmodel and spss use the same approache?

Comment: @Rocketq
1) Could you please define what you mean by "reliable p-value"? It is a special case of MLE p-value. So I suggest to look for theory of "asymptotic properties of maximum likelihood estimates" to gain overall understanding of its reliability.

Comment: @Rocketq 
2) Yes, Statsmodels do calculate p-values for logistic regression in the same way. The covariance matrix of parameters (statsmodels.base.model.LikelihoodModelResults.normalized_cov_params attribure) is calculated as inverse Hessian in the statsmodels.base.model.LikelihoodModel.fit method, and is further used for p-value estimation and other purposes. And as far as I know, SPSS does principally the same.

Comment: That looks great. Just one more question, that method looks pretty similar to Wald statistic or not?

Comment: Yes, this p-value is exactly the significance of Wald test. Both are based on the assumption that  the value```(estimate-hypothesis) / std.dev(estimate)``` is asymtotically standard normal, if the hypothesis is true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test_on_a_single_parameter

Comment: @DavidDale do you have a reference on why sklearn does not support statistical inference?

Comment: @kand because of focus. They just cannot support everything (with very limited resources), and they choose to cover different ML algorithms more fully, instead of doing other things.

Comment: @David Dale Do you make the point of the C term because you don't want a model that will overfit or C has a strong influence on the p_value?

Comment: C has strong influence on the coefficients themselves (and through them on the p-value, of course). Scikit-learn uses C=1 by default; Statsmodels doesn't regularize at all (which is equivalent to C=infinity). Therefore, if we want scikit-learn and statsmodels to have similar coefficients, we need to set C very high in scikit-learn.

Comment: Can we still use this function definition even if we have a different C, say, C = 0.5? Does the wald test result differ in this case?